# Unicity of Johnson-Wilson Theories

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, formal-groups

Let $E$ be a ring spectrum with a $p$-typical complex orientation. Then we call $E$ a *form of* $BP\langle n\rangle$ or a *generalized* $BP\langle n\rangle$ if the induced map

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[v_1,\dots, v_n] \subset BP_* \to E_*$$

is an isomorphism. Note here that the subring $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[v_1,\dots, v_n] \subset BP_*$ is canonical in the sense that it does not depend on whether we take the Araki or the Hazewinkel or other choices of $v_i$.

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37690/isomorphism-between-two-universal-p-typical-formal-group-laws) it was noted that different forms of $BP\langle 2 \rangle$ do not need to be equivalent as *ring* spectra, as the formal groups they carry are not isomorphic. On the other hand, Angeltveit and Lind have shown in a [recent preprint](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.01448v1.pdf) that all forms of $BP\langle n \rangle$ are equivalent as spectra after $p$-completion.

My question is about the corresponding situation for Jonson-Wilson theories. Say, we have again a ring spectrum $E$ with a $p$-typical orientation. Then we can call $E$ a *form of* $E(n)$ if there is a choice of $v_1,\dots, v_n$ such that the image of $v_n$ under the homomorphism

$$\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[v_1,\dots, v_n] \subset BP_* \to E_*$$

is invertible and the induced morphism $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[v_1,\dots, v_n, v_n^{-1}] \to E_*$ is an isomorphism.

Still we do not have multiplicative uniqueness, but we can ask for additive uniqueness. In cases of interest this might be reduced to the uniqueness result for forms of $BP\langle n \rangle$, but here an algebraic approach is also possible:

The coefficients of $E$ form a Landweber exact $BP_*$-module, so that

$$BP_*(X)\otimes_{BP_*} E_* \to E_*(X)$$

is an isomorphism for all spectra $X$. This can be rewritten in the language of stacks: If 
$$f: \mathrm{Spec}(E_{2*})//\mathbb{G}_m \to \mathcal{M}_{FG}$$
into the moduli stack of formal groups is the map classifiying the graded formal group over $E_{2*}$, then $E_{2*}(X) \cong \Gamma(\mathcal{F}_X^{even} \otimes f_*\mathcal{O}_*)$ and $E_{2*+1}(X) \cong \Gamma(\mathcal{F}_X^{odd} \otimes f_*\mathcal{O}_*)$. Here $\mathcal{O}_*$ is the graded structure sheaf of $\mathrm{Spec}(\pi_{2*}E)//\mathbb{G}_m$ and $(\mathcal{F}_X^{even}, \mathcal{F}_X^{odd})$ is the quasi-coherent sheaf on $\mathcal{M}_{FG}$ associated to the graded $(MU_*, MU_*MU)$-comodule $MU_*X$ for a spectrum $X$.

My question is now the following:

> Let an *algebraic Johnson-Wilson datum* consist of the following: A
>   commutative graded ring $E_*$ with a $p$-typical graded formal group
>   law such that $E_* \cong \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}[v_1, v_2,\dots, v_n^{\pm 1}]$ in the sense described above. Are then for any two algebraic
>   Johnson-Wilson data (of the same height $n$) the quasi-coherent
>   sheaves $f_*\mathcal{O}_*$ on $\mathcal{M}_{FG}$ isomorphic?

By the discussion above this algebraic uniqueness statement would imply the additive uniqueness of the Johnson-Wilson spectra.

I have the feeling that, if true, there should be an easy reason for this, which I am just missing.

Comment: Nice question. For $E$ and $E'$, if we want a map (not necessarily an isomorphism) we need a map $MU_* MU = MU_*[b_i] \to (E')_*$ of left $MU_*$-modules (so it assigns some invariant to each monomial in the $b_i$) that factors through inverting $\eta_R(v_n)$ and killing $\eta_R(b_k)$ for some regular sequence defining $E_*$. However, that's as far as general nonsense will get you.

Comment: My guess is that such a result would be something special to this stack and these affine schemes over it.